# Unable to re-enable Google Cloud AppEngine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I used to run a NodeJS Flexible Environment AppEngine application on my project and later disabled it. 
Now i am trying to deploy a Java based Standard Environment AppEngine application to the same project. 
When i tried to deploy i got following error

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Unable to deploy to application [project_name] with status [USER_DISABLED]: Deploying to stopped apps is not allowed.
```

Then realised i disabled the AppEngine in past. Now when i goto AppEngine > Settings and click on 'Enable Application' its saying enabling application and after some time its going back to the same state. I am getting the same issue while deploying.

Am i missing something here? Is anything else i need to do first to re-enable the disabled AppEngine Application?

Comment: Are you the project owner? Are there any helpful details in the activity view: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity Is there a reason to not use a different project for your new code?

Comment: Yes, I am the project owner. The reason to use the same project is to keep the url consistent across services. In the activity log i see two logs 1. Update App Engine Application 2. Completed: Update App Engine Application no sign of errors there

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem

Comment: @DoITInternational My problem still not resolved, better go with a new application, GCP team worked on my issue but couldn't resolve