# GAE not starting

Tags: google-app-engine

i can;t deploy app to GAE anymore.

- App deploy was always stuck with time out.
- Some days ago app was working fine. I was able to deploy. I'm sure.
- I pickup old version, just to eliminate possibility that something wrong with app
- I try to deploy with all reasonable parameters.
- I try delete all services (except default which i can't delete, however i uploaded basic one line app)
- I already try most of advice which i found on web
- I try to disable App engine.. It failed, however after some time i was able to Disable it.

Now i'm not able to enable GAE.. i see folowing error:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Unable to deploy to application [**************] with status [USER_DISABLED]: Deploying to stopped apps is not allowed.

Any advice is welcome:
- How to enable GAE
- How to avoid time outs during deploy App to GAE

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll have to re-enable the app before attempting to re-deploy, in the App Engine -> Settings -> Application Settings tab in the developer console.

Comment: standard or flex environment?

Comment: 1. Yes, i try to re-enable but always getting error.
2. flex enviroment

Comment: There may be some bug lurking, same error reported not long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089284/unable-to-re-enable-google-cloud-appengine-application

Comment: I think this may be related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900509 Comments indicate that a re-deployment after re-enabling gets the instances started again, Worth a try.

Comment: Yes, the issue tracker is probably much better for these kind of problems you can't really solve with code.

Answer (score 0):

The [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) is a good place to put bugs and/or feature requests. For faster and more urgent issues, contact the Google Cloud Platform support team directly and they will be able to assist you.

Your issue could also simple be a propagation delay, so if in 24/48 hours and you still can't, then it's likely a bug. Furthermore, you can always deploy to another project if it's all the same to you.

Comment: Thanks Ying Li. Unfortunately issue still exist after 24 hours (i will try after 48 too). Sure, i created new project and moved everything, but just afraid, that if it happen again i will need to move again and again.. :). And, yes, i sent issue to google support. Will keep updated If i get any news. Let's see